# Flutter how to call a function when first page of PageView.builder is shown?

Tags: flutter, dart

Im working with a `PageView.Builder` and I'm calling a function every time with `onPageChanged` after user swipes to next page. Now what actually doesn't work is calling this function on the first page.

Does anybody know how to do this? (In my context I can't work with `GestureDetector` as I need to call the function without doing any gesture)

```
body: 
           PageView.builder(
            controller: controller,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: list.length,
            onPageChanged: (page) {
              MYFUNCTION();
            },
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: list[index],
              child: Transform(
...
```

Comment: Hope you can do it by calling `MYFUNCTION` in `initState`..!?not sure if it suits your usecase though..

Comment: @srikanth7785 sadly no.. I need to get some informations from the index (PageView.Builder code is complex, just simplified it) so calling it in initstate is too early, as I'm working with providers and it results in setState or markrebuild call error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `Future.delayed`

```
someDummyFunction {
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:1), () => setState(() {
  //Your logic here
   }));
```

Hope it answers your question..

Answer (score 0):

okay I found a workaround.

as @srikanth7785 asked why not using `initState` and I said im getting trouble then with my `providers` and states, the following code called from `initState` worked for me:

```
callFirstFunction() {
Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => setState(() {
  //magic happens here
   }));
```

Comment: @srikanth7785  well nice that we talked about it! thats teamwork