# Flutter - How can I call a function when the PageView.builder appear on the screen?

Tags: flutter, function, dart, sharedpreferences

I have a function to callback in my code when the pageview appear, I know there is 'onPageChanged' but it only works when you turn to another page and don't work while you're on the first initial.

I use some data from the PageView.builder index in my function that's why I can't use the function outside the PageView code so is there any way to solve this.

I will appreciate that you take your time for helping me.

[this is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61929172/flutter-how-to-call-a-function-when-first-page-of-pageview-builder-is-shown/75935331#75935331)

if you can explain that question, it will be better for me

```
    PageView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.data.length ?? 3,
      controller: controller,
      onPageChanged: (value) async {
        var prefs =
            await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        await prefs.setString('img', img);
    
        print(img);
        getimg = img;
      },
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        img = '$api/wallpapers/' +
            snapshot.data[index]['wallpaper'];
        getimg = img;
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey,
            image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                image: NetworkImage(
                    '$api/wallpapers/' +
                        snapshot.data[index]
                            ['wallpaper'])),
          ),
         );
        },
       ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand your question, but you can call a function inside the itemBuilder and use an if if you want it to be called on a specific page

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
 function();
img = '$api/wallpapers/' +
snapshot.data[index]['wallpaper']
```

Comment: that's a place which i want to call the function but I want to call it when the pageview shown up, I mean when I navigate to that screen which contain the pageview run the function. thanks for your answer

Comment: the function you want to call is this one from shared? could you give more details about the function?

Comment: part 1 :: let me explain it: I have a ui which contain pageview inside a resized container and this pageview is inside a future builder, at the bottom of the screen outside the future builder i have a button, i use api to get some images from it and shown them inside a pageview.builder and when i press the button a data just added to the local database, the data is the correct image that showed in pageview, when i press the button it means i added the image to favorites and i want to change the color if the button icon, to do this i need a checker to check the local db :is there any......

Comment: part2 :: is there any data by this id or img link, and that checker is inside the function, when i navigate to the screen of page i want to call the function to see if i add the image to favorite or not, but everytime i need to scroll the page and get back to run the function which it's bad for me and my ui, hope you understand me if you want more explain send me a message on instagram i will show you how is that?

Comment: check if I understand: you add an image in the page builder, when passing the image to the side do you want to check if this image is in the favorites, if so do you want to change the color of the button?